# Loop EOF ssh -n can't create file

Tags: bash, ssh, eof

Hope this time it's not a duplicate. I didn't find anything.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/user/srv.txt
TICKET=task
while read LINE; do
    ssh -nT $LINE << 'EOF'
        touch info.txt
        hostname >> info.txt 
        ifconfig | grep inet | awk '$3 ~ "cast" {print $2}' >> info.txt
        grep -i ^server /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf >> info.txt 
        echo "- Done -" >> info.txt
EOF
ssh -nT $LINE "cat info.txt" >> $TICKET.txt
done < $FILE #End
```

My issue:

- if I only use `ssh $LINE` it will only ssh to the host on the first line and also display an error `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`
- using `ssh -T` , fix the error message above and it will create the file info.txt
- using `ssh -nT` , fix the error where ssh only read the first line but I get an error message `cat: info.txt: No such file or directory`. If I ssh to the hosts, I can confirm that there is no info.txt file in my home folder. and with `ssh -T`, I have this file in my home folder.

I tried with the option -t, also HERE, EOF without ' ... ' but no luck

Do I miss something?
Thanks for your help,
Iswaren

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I don't think you need two separate `ssh` commands. Just add `cat info.txt` to the end of the here document, and add `>> $TICKET.txt` to the first `ssh` comment, just before `<< 'EOF'` (or after `done`, if there's no other output in the body of the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

- If you invoke ssh without `-n` it may consume the $FILE input (it drains its stdin)
- If you invoke ssh with `-n` it won't read its stdin, so none of the commands will be executed

However, the first ssh has had its input redirected to come from a heredoc, so it does not need `-n`.

As stated in the comments, the second ssh call is not needed. Rather than piping into info.txt and then copying that into a local file, just output to the local file directly:

```
while read LINE; do
    ssh -T $LINE >>$TICKET.txt <<'EOF'
        hostname 
        ifconfig | grep inet | awk '$3 ~ "cast" {print $2}'
        grep -i ^server /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
        echo "- Done -"
EOF
done <$FILE
```

Comment: Thanks @jhnc for all this explanation.
Yeah I didn't think about for redirect everything to $ticket.txt instead of craete a local file.

It works! Cheers